# Calculate differences between pairs of consecutive variables, AND retain all original rows and columns using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate differences between pairs of consecutive variables in a rowwise manner, AND retain all rows using *dplyr* in R.

The first part of calculating differences works well on condition that the starting dataframe (*df2*) has no row with ALL NAs in the pairs (*var1-var9*) used in the calculations.

However I would like to tweak this solution, so such that besides calculating the required differences, it also retains the rows where the pairs (*var1-var9*) used in the calculations all have NAs in them, as well as all the columns that were present originally.

**Below is the code I am working with and dataset:**

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>%
    bind_cols(df2 %>%
                  rowid_to_column() %>%
                  gather(col, val, var1:var9) %>%
                  group_by(id) %>%
                  mutate(val = val - lag(val)) %>%
                  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
                  mutate(col = paste0("diff_", col)) %>%
                  spread(col, val)  %>%
                  select(contains("diff"))
    )
```

**Dataset:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(var1 = c(17, 16, 14, 16, 16, 11, 13, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 14, 16, 12, 16, 16, 16, 17, 14, 15, 13, 13, 16, 0, 13, 15, 
12, 10, 13, 16, 16, 15, 12, 15, 12, 11, 11, 16, 15, 14, 16, 0, 
15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 11, 16, 11, 16, 16, 14, 14, 0, 
12, 16, 16, 1, 11, 14, 16, 12, 11, 12, 16, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var2 = c(17, 16, 15, 17, 17, 16, 13, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 12, 16, 16, 16, 17, 14, 15, 13, 13, 16, 
0, 13, 15, 13, 10, 13, 16, 16, 15, 12, 16, 12, 11, 12, 16, 15, 
15, 17, 0, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 11, 16, 11, 16, 16, 
15, 14, 0, 13, 16, 16, 2, 11, 14, 16, 12, 16, 12, 16, 11, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var3 = c(17, 16, 15, 17, 
17, 16, 13, 17, 16, 16, 17, 15, 17, 13, 16, 17, 17, 18, 15, 16, 
13, 14, 17, 0, 13, 16, 13, 11, 14, 17, 16, 16, 12, 16, 13, 12, 
13, 16, 16, 16, 17, 1, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 15, 17, 11, 16, 
11, 16, 17, 17, 15, 0, 14, 17, 17, 11, 11, 16, 16, 12, 17, 12, 
16, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var4 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    var6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), var8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 25, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), var9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), wt = c(17, 16, 15, 17, 17, 16, 13, 17, 16, 16, 17, 
    15, 17, 13, 16, 17, 17, 18, 15, 16, 13, 14, 17, 0, 13, 16, 
    13, 11, 14, 17, 16, 16, 12, 16, 13, 12, 13, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
    1, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 16, 15, 17, 11, 16, 11, 16, 17, 17, 
    15, 0, 14, 17, 17, 11, 11, 16, 16, 12, 17, 12, 16, 7, 2, 
    5, 12, 9, 15, 19, 21, 3, 14, 47), plt = c(17, 16, 14, 16, 
    16, 11, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, 14, 16, 12, 16, 16, 16, 17, 14, 
    15, 13, 13, 16, 0, 13, 15, 12, 10, 13, 16, 16, 15, 12, 15, 
    12, 11, 11, 16, 15, 14, 16, 0, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 
    16, 11, 16, 11, 16, 16, 14, 14, 0, 12, 16, 16, 1, 11, 14, 
    16, 12, 11, 12, 16, 2, 2, 5, 12, 9, 15, 19, 21, 3, 14, 47
    ), dir = c(17, 16, 15, 17, 17, 16, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 
    16, 12, 16, 16, 16, 17, 14, 15, 13, 13, 16, 0, 13, 15, 13, 
    10, 13, 16, 16, 15, 12, 16, 12, 11, 12, 16, 15, 15, 17, 0, 
    15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 15, 16, 11, 16, 11, 16, 16, 15, 14, 
    0, 13, 16, 16, 2, 11, 14, 16, 12, 16, 12, 16, 11, 2, 5, 12, 
    9, 15, 19, 21, 3, 14, 47), conv = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 25, 2, 5, 12, 9, 15, 19, 21, 3, 14, 47), conv2 = c(17, 
    16, 14, 16, 16, 11, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, 14, 16, 12, 16, 16, 
    16, 17, 14, 15, 13, 13, 16, 0, 13, 15, 12, 10, 13, 16, 16, 
    15, 12, 15, 12, 11, 11, 16, 15, 14, 16, 0, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 15, 16, 11, 16, 11, 16, 16, 14, 14, 0, 12, 16, 16, 
    1, 11, 14, 16, 12, 11, 12, 16, 2, 2, 5, 12, 9, 15, 19, 21, 
    3, 14, 47), id = 1:80), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Remove the `filter` part and `ungroup`? This would be better with a *minimal* dataset. Two or three columns and to or three would necessary to express your question.

Comment: Something like: `df2 %>%
  bind_cols(df2 %>%
              rowid_to_column() %>%
              gather(col, val, var1:var9) %>%
              group_by(id) %>%
              mutate(val = val - lag(val)) %>%
              mutate(col = paste0("diff_", col)) %>%
              spread(col, val)  %>%
              ungroup() %>% 
              select(contains("diff"))
  ) `

Comment: Another option: `df2 %>%
       rowid_to_column() %>%
       pivot_longer(starts_with('var'), names_to=c("col"), values_to="val") %>% 
       group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(diff = val - lag(val)) %>%
       pivot_wider(names_from="col", values_from=c("val", "diff"))`